# Decline a PR when pipeline gets failed

Tags: yaml, devops, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket pipelines for PR raised pipeline, is there any way to write in bitbucket-pipelines.yml or in bitbucket settings to Cancel/Decline PR if pipeline gets failed at any step?

There are variables like "BITBUCKET_PR_ID", "BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE", which contains PR ID and exit status code, can we automate process by that?

MAIN OBJECTIVE: To cancel the pull-request if any step get failed in Bitbucket-Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an in-built function or similar that you can call from within BB pipelines that will decline the PR automatically. However, note that even if there isn't a way to decline the PR in-built to BB pipelines, there still is an [API endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-pull-request-id-decline-post) that allows you to do it.

You can check what the `BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE` is and depending on that, you can call the endpoint. You only need the `PR_ID` to pass as a parameter, which you already have.